# I want to create an HTML5 + python (tornado) based multiplayer game :)

Tags: python, facebook, html, websocket, game-engine

Following is what I have done so far:

1. Made a very simple python (tornado based) websocket server that echo back what it gets.
2. Made a separate javascript based game that I want to modify and make multiplayer.

Things I need to know :

1. I want to develop my python server so that it can handle multiplayer game. First requirement I guess would be to identify different users with uuid. But i dont know how to integrate it with websockets.
2. Other thing is to deploy it on facebook and have some features like invite friends, find a random player to play etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The most simple strategy is use Session https://sockjs-tornado.readthedocs.org/en/latest/mod_session.html
2. [Facebook developer docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/web/)